# How to Correctly Provide swDest?

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have installed [workbox-cli](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cli)

and using the config below, located in `config.js`

```
const {InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpack: function(config, env) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new InjectManifest({
        globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css}'],
        swSrc: path.join('public', 'custom-service-worker.js'),
        swDest: 'service-worker.js',
        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5000000,
      })
    );
    return config;
  }
}
```

and then running

```
workbox generateSW config.js
```

I get

> Your configuration is invalid:
>
> {
>    "webpack": function(config, env) {\n    config.plugins.push(\n      new InjectManifest({\n        >globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css}'],\n        swSrc: path.join('public', 'custom-service->worker.js'),\n        swDest: 'service-worker.js',\n        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: >5000000,\n      })\n    );\n    return config;\n  },
>    "swDest"     [1]: -- missing --
>   }
>
> [1] "swDest" is required

I am not sure what else to do because I am providing `swDest`

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view it looks fine. Only thing that comes up to my mind is to try set publicPath to empty string (''). I am using laravel-mix so this is my config.

```
mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
                swSrc: './public/sw.js',
                swDest: 'service-worker.js',
                maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5*1024*1024,
            })
        ],
        output: {
            publicPath: ''
        }
    };
});
```